# Expected initializer before nearPoint

Tags: c++

What could be possible error in this line?

```
const SPoint nearPoints[iloscKierunkow] = {SPoint(0, -1), SPoint(1, 0), SPoint(0, 1), SPoint(-1, 0)};
```

I get

> Error expected initializer before nearPoint

Sorounding code is

```
static const int TU_JESTEM = '+';
static const int NIE_BADANY = ' ';
static const int ZBADANY = '*';

const int iloscKierunkow = 4;
const int SPoint nearPoints[iloscKierunkow] = {SPoint(0, -1), SPoint(1, 0), SPoint(0, 1), SPoint(-1, 0)};

class Punkt
{
public:
    int x, y;

    Punkt(int Nx = 0, int Ny = 0)
    {//konstruktor
        x = Nx;
        y = Ny;
```

Comment: Is `SPoint` some class defined elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const int SPoint nearPoints[iloscKierunkow] = {SPoint(0, -1), SPoint(1, 0), SPoint(0, 1), SPoint(-1, 0)};
```

Declares its type as int and then SPoint. I'm guessing you meant:

```
const SPoint nearPoints[iloscKierunkow] = {SPoint(0, -1), SPoint(1, 0), SPoint(0, 1), SPoint(-1, 0)};
```

Comment: AAA yes sory there should be no int dunno how it came there but still error stay same

Comment: Once you get rid of the 'int' it looks fine to me. I tested in gcc with a dummy SPoint class and it compiles fine. Have you defined SPoint prior to this line?

Comment: ok im so dumb really hehe i just resolve it  thx Jarra McIntyre this is what happen when u copy code from other class ;p hehe

Answer (score 0):

look at it:

```
const int SPoint nearPoints[iloscKierunkow]
```

'int' is unnecessary here